# Observable from a RESTful paged collection

Tags: json, rest, angular, rxjs, hateoas

On one hand, I have a RESTful HAL HATEOAS collection which looks like this :

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "pages": 18,
    "total": 174,
    "_links": {
        "self":  { "href": "/users?page=1&limit=10" },
        "first": { "href": "/users?page=1&limit=10" },
        "last":  { "href": "/users?page=18&limit=10" },
        "next":  { "href": "/users?page=2&limit=10" }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "bob",
                "_links": { "self": { "href": "/users/1" } }
            },
            ...
        ]
     }
}
```

On the other hand, I have an Angular 2 app.

```
public getUsers(uri: string = this.baseURI): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get(uri)
    .map(res => res.json()._embedded.users as User[])
    .flatMap(d => d) // Transform the flux of arrays in flux of users
    .catch(this.handleError);
} // Get only the 10th first users
```

What I'm trying to do have an observable of Users which will append data while `_links.next != null`

Modified service

```
public getUsers(uri: string = this.baseURI): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get(uri)
    .do(res => {
        const uri = JSON.parse(res._body)._links.next.href;
        this.nextUri = uri ? uri : null;
     })
    .map(res => res.json()._embedded.users as User[])
    .flatMap(d => d) // Transform the flux of arrays in flux of users
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Recursive function

```
loadAll(uri: string) {
    read(uri)
      .subscribe(
        user => {
          this.stockedUsers.push(user);
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => {
          if (this.nextUri) {
            this.loadAll(this.nextUri);
          }
        }
      );
}
```

Does someone know how to achieve this properly ?
I want to keep thes advantages of the RxJS flux.

**UPDATE/ANSWER**
Silly me ! I think I answered myself. Maybe this will help others :

```
public read(uri: string = this.baseURI): Observable<User> {
  return Observable.create(observer => this.iteratePages(observer, uri));
}

private iteratePages(observer: Observer<User>, uri): void {
  if (uri == null) { return observer.complete(); }
  this.http.get(uri).subscribe(res => {
    const data = res.json();
    for (const user of data._embedded.users) {
      observer.next(user as User);
    }
    const nextUri = (data._links && data._links.next) ? data._links.next.href : null;
    this.iteratePages(observer, nextUri);
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to fetch all the users until you have reached the end in a single shot? Or are you thinking about an infinite scroll?

Comment: More like an infinite scroll with an "onComplete" event.
But I think I find a way by creating a new Observable.

I'll made some tests and I'll update my question.